# Left and Right Shift in java for byte and short types

Tags: java, byte, bit-shift, short

I'd like to ask a question in java about left and right shift ... I understand them well when done with int and long but i have some problems in understanding how the operation is done with byte and short since byte and short are promoted first to int .. the most mysterious part comes when promoting a negative short or negative byte value to int .... what can i do if i want to save the promoted byte or short value back in a byte or short variable ... if any one explain the whole procedure/operation to me it will be helpful .... thanks

Comment: What's with all the ellipses ... it doesn't make sense ...

Comment: Have you tried casting?

Comment: consider the first part of the question only for now ... say I am going to save the result in an int before any cast ... what will be the behavior of the shift on byte and short

Comment: "what will be the behavior of the shift on byte and short" Why not give it a go?

Comment: what does sign extend mean and how it is related to promotion of negative-valued short variable or negative-valued byte variable to int

Comment: how to make a test program ?

Comment: @Eng_Boody Just make some tests. You will see that the sign is not an issue due to the [Two's Comlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: @Eng_Boody create a Junit test

Comment: @AlexWien I am beginner at java, what is Junit test ? thnx

Comment: Its a test case, a verry good possibility to test such things. Ask Google about "Junit"